# PHP Wordpress optimization my loop code

Tags: php

I'm just learning PHP, and I'm using get_terms to get some text descriptions from the CMS, but i want to assign 3 variables to only 3 of my woocommerce tags. 
My code works well, but I just want to learn if there's a better way to filter by $tag_descrip->name than using if conditions.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$tag_descrip = get_terms( 'product_tag', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );
$count = count($tag_descrip);


if ( $count > 0 ){

 foreach ( $tag_descrip as $tag_descrip ) {

 if($tag_descrip->name == "parfum_bestof")
   {$title_new1 = $tag_descrip->description ;}

 if($tag_descrip->name == "tshirt_bestof")
   {$title_new2 = $tag_descrip->description ;}

 if($tag_descrip->name == "child_bestof")
   {$title_new3 = $tag_descrip->description ;}



 }



}

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Generic PHP questions are off-topic here. You could try asking this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It isn't necessarily off-topic... I *think* the OP is asking how to query 3, specific tags?  But I can't really tell because I don't know the use case for the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there is not better option, but to speed it up little you can use wordpress transient, see documentation: http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

your code would look like this (and i cleaned it bit and used function empty to check array...):

```
<?php

if ( false === ( $tag_descrip = get_transient( 'tag_descrip' ) ) ) {

     $tag_descrip = get_terms( 'product_tag', 'orderby=count&hide_empty=0' );

     set_transient( 'tag_descrip ', $tag_descrip );
}


if ( !empty($tag_descrip) ){

 foreach ( $tag_descrip as $tag_descrip ) {

 if($tag_descrip->name == "parfum_bestof")
   $title_new1 = $tag_descrip->description;

 if($tag_descrip->name == "tshirt_bestof")
   $title_new2 = $tag_descrip->description;

 if($tag_descrip->name == "child_bestof")
   $title_new3 = $tag_descrip->description;

}


}

?>
```

Comment: `foreach ( $tag_descrip as $tag_descrip )` – there is some room for improvement in the variable names … ;)

Comment: Thanks ! Seems like a good idea, I'm going to try it too but what's meaning of the operator "===" in PHP code, why we use "===" instead of "==" ?

Comment: Whereas the "===" operator is type strict, "==" will attempt to cast the operands. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).